# Angularjs ng-include not including any view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I keep trying to set my ng-include as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/app.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Airports</h1>
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="airport in airports">
            <a href="" ng-click="setAirport(airport.code)">
              {{airport.code}} - {{airport.name}}
            </a> -
            <a href="" ng-click="editAirport(airport.code)">
              Editar
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <p ng-show="currentAirport">Current airpot: {{currentAirport.name}}</p>
      </div>
      <!--el ng include le indica que puede incluir un scope (.html)-->
      <div ng-include src="formURL"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My JS script (app.js):

```
function AppCtrl ($scope){
    $scope.airports={
        "STL":{
            "code":"STL",
            "name":"Lambert-St Airport",
            "city":"san louis",
            "destinations": [
                "LAX",
                "MKE"
            ]
        }
    };
    $scope.formURL= 'partials/form.html';
    $scope.currentAirport = null;

    $scope.setAirport = function (code) {
        $scope.currentAirport = $scope.airports[code];
    };

    $scope.editAirport = function (code) {
        $scope.editing = $scope.airports[code];
    };
}
```

And finally form.html

```
<div ng-show="editing">
    <h3>Edit Airport</h3>
    <input ng-model="editing.name" value="" class="input-xlarge"/>
</div>
```

I have tried to show the form, changing the url, writing the complete url but it doesn't seems to work. Although when I click on the airports, the page shows correctly.

If anyone can point me in the right direction that'd be great. Sorry for the huge post, it needed a bit of explaining to make it coherent. Hopefully it makes sense. Thanks.

```
My directory:

exampleAngular
   |_css
   |_img
   |_js
   |_controllers
        |_app.js
   |_lib
        |_angular.min.js
        |_angular-resource.min.js
   |_partials
        |_form.html
        |_airport.html
   |_index.html
```

Comment: I put this in a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fEDrxmjSwsZMURaN5G0L?p=preview). Not sure what you're intending, but form.html seems to be displayed correctly in here. You only see it after clicking edit because you have `ng-show="editing"`. Can you be more specific about what "doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: When I click "Editar" nothing happens, is like is I didn't click it.

Comment: Does the plunker work for you?

Comment: In plunker it works, but when I copy the same code without changes it  doesn't work. My diretory:

angularexample
  angularexample/form.html
  angularexample/index.html
  angularexample/script.html

And when downloading and click "Editar" the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plunker provided by  Andyrooger works fine without modification, there are however a few thing you should change.

1) `ng-include` is used without `src` when using the directive as an attribute, so it should be `ng-include="formUrl"`

2) Use object properties rather then the entire object on `ng-show`

Change HTML to,

```
<div ng-show="editing.airport">
<h3>Edit Airport</h3>
<input ng-model="editing.name" value="" class="input-xlarge"/>
</div>
```

Also be aware of scope inheritances, change Controller

```
$scope.editing = {};
// Inside function
$scope.editing.airport = $scope.airports[code]
```

Answer (score 1):

Going by your comments it seems your `formURL` is incorrect...

You set it on this line

```
$scope.formURL= 'partials/form.html';
```

but then you say your *form.html* is in the same directory as your *index.html*. `formURL` is a path relative to the directory that *index.html* is in. So either

- Put *form.html* in a **partials** directory (*angularexample/partials/form.html*)

  or
- Set `formURL` as so

  ```
  $scope.formURL= 'form.html';
  ```

Comment: Thanks, but actually the directory is:
angularExample
  angularExample/css
  angularExample/img
  angularExample/js
    angularExample/js/controllers
      angularExample/js//controllers/app.js
    angularExample/js/lib